# Using different parameters for different tests in Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am working with embedded firmware testing using Python 3.9 and Pytest. We are working with multiple devices, and run different tests run on different devices. It would be very nice to be able to reuse test fixtures for each device - however I am running into difficulty parameterizing test fixtures.

Currently I have something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", params=["device1", "device2"])
def connect(request):
  jlink.connect(request.param)

@pytest.mark.device1
def test_device1(connect):
  # test code

@pytest.mark.device2
def test_device2(connect)
  # test code
```

The behavior I would like is that param "device1" is used for test_device1, and param "device2" is used for test_device2. But the default Pytest behavior is to use all params for all tests, and I am struggling to find a way around this. Is there a way to specify which params to use for certain markers?

I should also mention, I am an embedded C developer and have been learning Python as I've worked on this project, so my general Python/Pytest knowledge may be a bit lacking.

EDIT: I think I found a workaround, but I'm not super happy with it. I have separated the tests for each device into different folders, and in each folder, have a device_cfg.json file. The test fixture opens the cfg file to know which device to connect to.

EDIT2: This doesn't even work because of Pytest scoping...

Answer (score 0):

@pytest.mark.parametrize: parametrizing test functions

The builtin pytest.mark.parametrize decorator enables parametrization of arguments for a test function. Here is a typical example of a test function that implements checking that a certain input leads to an expected output:

```
# content of test_expectation.py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html

Hope it'll help you

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not what I'm looking for. I would like to be able to parameterize a test fixture based on marks. So for all the device1 tests, I would like it to call connect(device1), and for all the device2 tests, call connect(device2). I do not need to run a single test multiple times with different inputs.